# Javascript XML object - Undefined

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

The following code brings back my id.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://brewslocal.com/brewery-images-xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  document.getElementById("photoBox").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].id;
}
```

```html
<div id="photoBox"></div>
```

When I change to the next attribute imageurl it comes back undefined.

```js
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myFunction(this);
  }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://brewslocal.com/brewery-images-xml", true);
xhttp.send();

function myFunction(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  document.getElementById("photoBox").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].imageurl;
}
```

```html
<div id="photoBox"></div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Element.getAttribute('attributeName')` to get the attribute value from this custom HTML element.

```
function myFunction(xml) {
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  document.getElementById("photoBox").innerHTML = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("image")[0].getAttribute('imageurl');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
function myFunction(xml) {
var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('title')[0];
var y = x.childNodes[0];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
y.nodeValue;
```

}